# How Color the PathGraph Showing Multiple Shortest Paths on the US Counties Map

Tags: graphs-and-networks, geography, geographics

Below is code for mapping the connectivity of US counties. It comes from the Mathematica reference on "Connectivity of US Counties". I've highlighted 3 shortest paths shown in red. However, when I combine all 3 shortest paths into the single US map, the one running from California to Massachusetts is now very faded when I use the Show All command. Any advice on how to make these 3 shortest paths, when plotted together on a single map of the US counties, be displayed more brightly or even show thicker red line segments along those 3 paths?

Many thanks!!

```
Length[counties = 
   Flatten[EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", 
      "ContinentalUSStates"]["Subdivisions"]]];
AppendTo[counties, 
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"DistrictOfColumbia", 
    "DistrictOfColumbia", "UnitedStates"}]];
bordering = EntityValue[counties, "BorderingCounties"];
Length[missingpos = Position[bordering, _Missing]];
counties = Delete[counties, missingpos];
bordering = Delete[bordering, missingpos];
Length[edges = 
   DeleteDuplicates[
    Sort /@ Flatten[
      MapThread[
       Thread[UndirectedEdge[##]] &, {counties, bordering}]]]];
Graph[counties, edges];
pos = GeoPosition[EntityValue[counties, "Position"]];
proj = {"LambertAzimuthal", 
   "Centering" -> 
    Entity["City", {"Topeka", "Kansas", "UnitedStates"}]};
projpos = First@GeoGridPosition[pos, proj];
graph = Graph[counties, edges, VertexCoordinates -> projpos, 
   EdgeStyle -> Lighter[Lighter[Lighter[Blue]]]];
Length[path11 = 
   FindShortestPath[graph, 
    Entity[
     "AdministrativeDivision", {"LosAngelesCounty", "California", 
      "UnitedStates"}], 
    Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"SuffolkCounty", 
      "Massachusetts", "UnitedStates"}]]];
Length[path22 = 
   FindShortestPath[graph, 
    Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"LosAngelesCounty", 
      "California", "UnitedStates"}], 
    Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"IndianRiverCounty", "Florida", 
      "UnitedStates"}]]];
{HighlightGraph[graph, PathGraph[path11]], 
 HighlightGraph[graph, PathGraph[path22]]}
Length[path33 = 
   FindShortestPath[graph, 
    Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"ClatsopCounty", "Oregon", 
      "UnitedStates"}], 
    Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"IndianRiverCounty", "Florida", 
      "UnitedStates"}]]];
{HighlightGraph[graph, PathGraph[path11]], 
 HighlightGraph[graph, PathGraph[path22]], 
 HighlightGraph[graph, PathGraph[path33]]}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Highlight all of them at once.

```
HighlightGraph[graph, PathGraph /@ {path11, path22, path33}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also make them be the same color.

```
HighlightGraph[graph, Style[PathGraph[#], Red] & /@ {path11, path22, path33}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Domen: Once again, much appreciated ... regards ... prg